# Best practice for creating new application in same namespace

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

We have a large .NET solution with several projects all stored in a single TFS Collection. We are a small development team that develops mostly internal software and we don't normally do much branching or merging. We are about to totally redevelop one of our applications from the ground up so we are going to be starting fresh with a new project. This project should have the same namespace, name, assembly name, etc. as the project that it's replacing, but during this time we will still need to support and maintain the old project as well as all the other projects in the solution.

What is the right way to do this? Should I branch the entire solution or just the project in question? If the latter, how do I handle dependencies back to the rest of the solution?

Comment: Once the new replacement project has been shipped, is it likely that both the old and new application will run in tandem for a period of time (days, weeks, months)?

Comment: I'm sure we will deploy the new application in a dev environment prior to shipping, but it's a direct replacement for the old application so they shouldn't run in tandem once it ships.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the redeveloped application is going to entirely replace the existing application, and assuming you have existing Main and Development branches like so:

```
Main (solution containing live v1.x application)
 |
 +---> Development (solution containing v1.(x+1) application)
```

I would create a new branch for the solution from the Main branch, into which the v2.0 application shall be created:

```
Main (solution containing live v1.x application)
 |
 +---> Development (solution containing v1.(x+1) application)
 |
 +---> Dev2.0 (solution containing v2.0 application)
```

This way:

- changes to the existing V1.x codebase, *and your other projects*, can be worked on within the v1 branch;
- the v2 branch would being used solely for the redevelopment;
- any updates to existing projects that the v2.0 app requires can be picked up from the Main branch after being merged back in from the V1.0 Dev branch.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to branch the whole solution. This way, you can maintain it separately while its in production. When the new code-base is ready, you can lock the original branch for safe-keeping. Its easier to manage and you'll always know which version of the application your working in.

Comment: So for other projects in the solution, would you maintain them in the new branch or the old?

Comment: The new branch is where the maintenance of the projects would be done in. Of course, there's always exceptions. For example, if you find a bug in the original code-base, you can fix it in that branch and (if applicable) merge the fix to the current code-base. New features would obviously only be done in the new branch.